# Why can't upload three files with FileUpload?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, file-upload, apache-commons-fileupload

i'm trying to upload three images to my server, is working, but upload always the last file selected by the user, not the three selected.

Here's my code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    boolean multipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

    if (multipart) {
        DiskFileItemFactory fileItemFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

        fileItemFactory.setSizeThreshold(5 * 1024 * 1024); //5 MB
        fileItemFactory.setRepository(tmpDir);

        ServletFileUpload uploadHandler = new ServletFileUpload(fileItemFactory);
        try {
            List items = uploadHandler.parseRequest(request);

            Iterator itr = items.iterator();

            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();

                File file = new File(dir, generateNewName());
                item.write(file);
            }
        } catch (FileUploadException ex) {
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

--
UPDATE:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file1" />
            <br />

            <input type="file" name="file2" />
            <br />

            <input type="file" name="file3" />
            <br />

            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />

        </form>
    </body>
```

UPDATE 2:

I found my error:
when i called the method `generateNewName()`  return a string that contains (date)+(hour)+(miliseconds) , i think this should be enough to generate a new name every time but returns the same name always, so this way rewrite the same file every time.

Sorry for any inconvenience and thank you guys by the help.

Best regards,
Valter Henrique.

Comment: have you debugged the line `List items = uploadHandler.parseRequest(request)` to see if `request` is coming with 3 files? Can you also post your html/jsp code?

Comment: Valter, is the file that is uploaded intact? Meaning: you said only the 3rd file gets uploaded; is that identical to the file that the user uploaded or is it mangled?

Comment: @bluefoot i had not debugged my code, but i put some 'system.out' and that's everthing ok , none exception is launched.
i gonna post my jsp code

Comment: @Guss , the file is identical, i mean, intact, this method to upload files already works to upload a file, but now i need to upload three files, instead one. Follow the logic it should works this way , but is not what it happens =)

Comment: Hey guys, i finally discover my error, sorry bother you =)

Answer (score 1):

Even though you nailed down your own problem (kudos for you, I'd suggest to post an answer on this question yourself), I would still like to recommend to use [`File#createTempFile()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29) instead to generate an unique filename. This Java SE provided API is guaranteed to create an unique file on the given path.

Here's an example which does that based on the name/extension of the uploaded file.

```
String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());
String fileNamePrefix = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(fileName) + "_";
String fileNameSuffix = "." + FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName);

File file = File.createTempFile(fileNamePrefix, fileNameSuffix, dir);
item.write(file);
// ...
```

*The `FilenameUtils` is from Commons IO which you should already have in the classpath anyway since it's a required dependency of Commons FileUpload.*